# Computing the average of measurements with an associated uncertainty

Tags: mean, uncertainty

I think this might be a silly (or a really basic) thing to ask, but I have not been able to see this clearly. Suppose I have $N$ measurements of a certain magnitude $x$, each with an associated uncertainty, $\Delta x$. How do I compute the mean of these measurements and also the uncertainty of the mean? I know one could use the standard error if the data didn't have any uncertainties: $$\Delta(\bar{x}) = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$$

But I am not very sure about the best way to proceed in the case of the raw data already having associated uncertainties. I feel like just performing an error propagation calculation is probably a wrong approach. And by this I mean:

$$\Delta(\bar{x}) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N \Big{(}\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial x_i}\Big{)}(\Delta x_i)^2}$$

In case this is relevant: I have computed a parameter by performing several least squares regressions over my available data, and every time the result has been very similar. So now I have six values, each one with an associated uncertainty, but I need to know their arithmetic mean as well as the uncertainty of their mean.

Comment: I recommend looking up “Propagation of uncertainty” in wiki and I also recommend looking at this: QUAM:2012.P1 (EURACHEM/CITAC Guide, “Quantifying Uncertainty in Analytical Measurement”, 3rd Ed., 2012.) You can easily find it online, for free, and it is all about quantifying uncertainties in measurements, though with an obvious focus on analytical chemistry-related measurements.

Comment: Can you tell us what this *associated uncertainty* is? What does it represent? How is it calculated? ...

Comment: I have two values, which are the slope of a line corresponding to a least squares fit performed on R. The uncertainty is the standard error reported by R. These two values correspond to a parameter related to a diffraction grating film, the "grating constant".